# Prove that $\int_1^\infty (x^{-(s+1)/2}+x^{s/2-1})\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-\pi n^2 x}\right)dx$ is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove that  $$G:s\longmapsto \int_1^\infty  (x^{-(s+1)/2}+x^{s/2-1})\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-\pi n^2 x}\right)dx$$ is holomorphic over $\mathbb C$ ?

**Attempt**

I have that $$s\longmapsto (x^{-(s+1)/2}+x^{s/2-1})\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-\pi n^2 x}\right)$$ is holomorphic over $\mathbb C$.

Let $$G_N(x)=\int_1^N  (x^{-(s+1)/2}+x^{s/2-1})\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-\pi n^2 x}\right)dx,$$
that is holomorphic. I'm trying to show that $G_N(x)\to G(x)$ uniformly on every compact, i.e. that $$\left|\int_N^\infty ...\right|\leq u_n\to 0$$

but I have problem to majorate.

Comment: Does it have any particular reason for not being holomorphic? No, hence it is holomorphic. :D (just joking)

Comment: Indeed, it is pretty simple to notice that $\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ is a function in the Schwarz space $\mathcal{S}([1,+\infty))$, and it has a very fast decay on the right half-plane.

Comment: @Watson: It's exactly what I tried to do, and I gess that my $G_N$ is the one. But I have problem to conclude.